# Sharepoint 2010 doesn't show filter choices within a folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wss

I am using WSS and Sharepoint 2010. I have the next problem.
I created a new document library. Then I uploaded some documents in it. When I want to filter my items in the root folder by one of the columns, I click to "Show all filter choices" in the header and choose the value from the list. All is fine. But! I created a new folder and uploaded some documents in it, the function "Show all filter choices" (a new folder is the current directory in this moment) had showed only choices from the root folder (it ignored the items in my new folder). How can I force SP to show only choices of items within the newfolder? I'll appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: I have found the reason of this issue, but haven't recently resolved it. The filter choice doesn't work because of too many items in the folder (about 1000). Creating indexes didn't bring any help. Filtering have resolved the problem, but I need to have all items at the same time, in other words I can't apply one definite filter. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint Designer,
and create a data view web part with data source as the document library and display the files alone. In Data Source Properties, Item and Folder scope select Recursive option. Also if you dont want the folders to be listed in the view apply the filter condition as content type not equal to folder.

I seriously doubt if you can force the SP to do this with only site level changes.

Thanks!